# ¿Cómo poner signo de "Q" en sql server 2014? y ¿Como hacer que se visualize el signo "Q" en un datagridview en visual basic.net?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

tenia una duda, es que estoy haciendo una base de datos de clientes morosos de una tienda, pero yo vivo en guatemala, y el signo de moneda de aqui es el Quetzal "Q", solo eh visto como hacer que me tire con el signo de $, pero no de "Q", es posible incluir ese simbolo en una columna de tipo moneda en sql server?, otra pregunta que tengo es que no se si eso se puede mostrar en visual basic.net en un datagridview?

Comment: Tienes la opción de modificar el LOCALE (la config regional) en la BD o en presentación. Si lo que te interesa es que se vea en tu Datagridview, posiblemente es en la aplicación donde debes lidiar con eso y dejas la configuración de moneda en la BD sin cambios. Si esto es lo que buscas, es necesario que nos compartas el código correspondiente para ver qué estás intentando hacer :)

Answer (score 0):

Cuando necesitas utilizar en TSQL un símbolo de moneda, una de las opciones es recurrir a la función format.

A la misma, le tienes que establecer 3 parámetros. Lo primero la fuente de datos. En el caso del ejemplo una variable, pero que puede ser una columna o expresión. El segundo, un patrón de formato. En el caso de las monedas C. El tercero la codificación regional que le corresponde. En el caso de Guatemala, es-GT.

```
declare @moneda money = 5.3
select format(@moneda,'c','es-GT');
```

[image: resultado]

Por tanto si el dataGrid lo alimentas con una query, entonces puedes hacerlo desde TSQL.
Pero lo más normal, es utilizar la aplicación para dar formatos.

Para esto tienes que establecer la codificación cultural.

[Culture Info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.twoletterisolanguagename?view=netframework-4.6)

[DataGridView Vb Currency](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1084eb2a-aed5-470b-a4b4-d01cf300bfbc/how-to-set-a-column-in-data-grid-view-to-show-currency?forum=vbgeneral)